# Scipy error? IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

I am trying to run this code, and I am getting the error below after running it. I am not sure if it is my version of SciPy or Python or a bug. somewhere. I am using `Python 2.7.11` and running on OSx.

```
from pylab import *
from ddeint import ddeint

def model(Y,t,d):
    x,y = tuple(Y(t))
    print(x,y)
    xd,yd = tuple(Y(t-d))
    return array([0.5*x-0.5*x*y, -0.5*y + 0.5*xd*yd])

g = lambda t : array([1,2])
tt = linspace(2,30,20000)

for d in [0]:
    print('d', d)
    yy = ddeint(model,g,tt,fargs=(d,))
    # WE PLOT X AGAINST Y
    plot(yy[:,0], yy[:,1], lw=2, label='delay = %.01f'%d)

legend()
```

The error I am receiving:

> IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2

Thank you!!

Comment: What is `ddeint`?   What arguments does it take?  Where does the Error occur?  Your code is incomplete, and your problem description is also incomplete.

Comment: If something is size 2, it will not have an index 2, only 0 and 1. For more detailed help see the comment above.

Comment: The problem came from this website: http://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/10/22/delay-differential-equations-in-python/ ddeint is for delay differential equations. The description of the problem says, The variable Y can be a vector, which means that you can solve DDE systems of several variables. Here is a version of the famous Lotka-Volterra two-variables system, where we introduce a delay dd. For d=0d=0 the system is a classical Lotka-Volterra system ; for d≠0d≠0 the system undergoes an important amplification.